# Problem with installing OpenCV using Visual Studio and CMake (error code: MSB3073)

Tags: opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I was trying to install OpenCV to import it in some Python project. I was using [this guide](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html) to build it from source. I've gotten to the 16th point without much trouble more or less. Now when I try to build the INSTALL project, I'm getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy9nC.jpg):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"E:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets    148
```

Double clicking this error points to `<Exec/>` part of this code in the `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets` file:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PostBuildEventUseInBuild)'!='false'">
  <Message Text="%(PostBuildEvent.Message)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Message)' != '' and '%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''" Importance="High" />
  <Exec Command="%(PostBuildEvent.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)" Condition="'%(PostBuildEvent.Command)' != ''"/>
```

Edit1:
Adding the full error log I got, unless I'm looking for it in the wrong place.

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: "E:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 80 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide the **full** error log as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: Hello, feels weird to finally post something instead of just lurking. Sorry about that img, I added it initially because the logs in form of a quote were quite unreadable, though they look much better after your correction.
I added the logs I got as per your request, at least I believe so

Comment: Just a guess: You are installing into `Program Files`, but don't have rights to write into this dir.

Comment: I did that and rebuilt everything and it seems to be working fine. No idea why i hadn't tried that before myself... Thank you a lot tho!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed, as indicated by @arrowd, that Visual Studio's permissions are not sufficient. Just run Visual Studio as administrator and then the install will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solution by @arrowd worked for me. just to show the steps how to fix this issue. First go to the build folder and right click, go to security tab and click edit. check the Full control box. Open your cmd as administrator than go the same directory as Opencv.sln.
run it from there than right click on INSTAll than build

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps:

1. Navigate to your *build* folder
2. Right click on **ALL-BUILD.vcxproj**
3. Select *properties*
4. Select *Security* tab
5. Select *Edit*
6. Check *Full Control* Box
7. Open **ALL-BUILD.vcxproj**
8. Right click on *INSTALL* and select *Rebuild*

Worked for me.